# Replacing a url

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have a Xslt code .

```
<xsl:value-of select="XSLTHelper:geturlpath()"/>
```

this is the value of xslt:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/productlisting.aspx?onxurl=%2fproducts%2fkonference--og-skrivemapper&fullurl=%2fproducts%2fkonference--og-skrivemapper.aspx&at=privat
```

I want to remove the &at=private.how can i achive this.anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `XSLTHelper:geturlpath` is a custom XSLTHelper extension. If that is the case you are probably much quicker removing the querysting in the extension method itself.